# Find a fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ which satisfies the given condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions

Find a fraction such that all of $\frac{m}{n}$, $\frac{m+1}{n+1}$, $\frac{m+2}{n+2}$, $\frac{m+3}{n+3}$, $\frac{m+4}{n+4}$, $\frac{m+5}{n+5}$ are reducible by cancellation. Condition: $m≠n$.

What I tried was... I wrote $$\frac{m}{n}=k$$ Then, I replaced $m$ in the fractions as $nk$. And after a bit of simple manipulation, I obtained $$k+\frac{1-k}{n+1},$$ $$k+\frac{2-k}{n+2},$$ $$k+\frac{3-k}{n+3},$$ $$k+\frac{4-k}{n+4},$$ $$k+\frac{5-k}{n+5}$$ Now I do not know how to proceed any further.

Comment: Hint:  to get started, note that if $m,n$ are both even then we can already reduce $\frac mn, \frac {m+2}{n+2}, \frac {n+4}{m+4}$ so that you only need to worry about three of the fractions.

Comment: Why do you assume $\frac m n$ is an integer? Being "reducible by cancellation" just means that $m$ and $n$ are not coprime, doesn't it?

Comment: I did not say k was an integer. It represents the fraction after being reduced.

Comment: I mean it cannot be reduced any further

Comment: $60$ is divisible by all of $1,2,3,4,5,6$, so $m=61^2$, $n=61$ oughta work.

Comment: Gcd((61^2+1),( 61+1))

Comment: =1(contd. From last comment)

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m=30a$ and $n=30b$, then

$${m\over n}={30a\over30b}\\{m+2\over n+2}={2(15a+2)\over2(15b+1)}\\{m+3\over n+3}={3(10a+1)\over3(10b+1)}\\{m+4\over n+4}={2(15a+2)\over2(15b+2)}\\\text{and}\\{m+5\over n+5}={5(6a+1)\over5(6b+1)}$$ are all reducible.  It remains to choose $a$ and $b$ so that

$$30a+1\over30b+1$$

is reducible.  If we try $b=1$, we see we need $31\mid30a+1$, or $a\equiv1$ mod $31$, so $a=32$ does the trick. Thus $m/n=960/30$ has the desired property.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit cheeky, and probably not what the question meant, but if $m=n$, the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Extremely sorry. I forgot to mention that condition in the question. Will edit it at once

Answer (score 1):

Simple computer search gives:

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
  m & n \\ \hline
  212 & 2 \\
  213 & 3 \\
  214 & 4 \\
  215 & 5 \\
  300 & 90 \\
  301 & 91 \\
  324 & 114 \\
  325 & 115 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Further observation:

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
  n \equiv m \pmod{\lambda} & \lambda \\ \hline
  2,3,4,5 & 210 \\
  6,7 & 462 \\
  8,9,10,11 & 858 \\
  10,11 & 1430 \\
  12,13 & 1326 \\
  12,13 & 2210 \\
  14,15,16,17 & 1938 \\
  14,15 & 3230 \\
  16,17 & 4522 \\
  18,19 & 2622 \\
  18,19 & 6118 \\
  20,21,22,23 & 690 \\
  20,21 & 1610 \\
  20 & 3795 \\ 
  24,25 & 870 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

If I just had to do it for $\frac mn, \frac {m+1}{n+1}, \frac {m+2}{n+2}$ I would note as in lulu's comment that if $m$ and $n$ are both even we satisfy the first and last.  If $m$ and $n$ are both one less than a multiple of $3$ we satisfy the second.  A couple even numbers that are one less than a multiple of $3$ are $8$ and $14$ so that is one solution.  Can you build on this to handle your problem?  You will get a system of modular equations and can use the Chinese remainder theorem to make sure there is a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed $n$ a solution is given by

> $$m=n+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)=n+\frac{(n+5)!}{(n-1)!}$$

indeed

$$\frac{m}{n}=\frac{n+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}{n}\\=1+(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)$$

$$\frac{m+1}{n+1}=\frac{n+1+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}{n+1}\\=1+n(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)$$

$$\frac{m+2}{n+2}=\frac{n+2+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}{n+2}\\=1+n(n+1)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)$$

$$\frac{m+3}{n+3}=\frac{n+3+n(n+1)(n+3)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}{n+3}=\\1+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+4)(n+5)$$

$$\frac{m+4}{n+4}=\frac{n+4+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}{n+4}\\=1+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+5)$$

$$\frac{m+5}{n+5}=\frac{n+5+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}{n+5}\\=1+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$$

Comment: What about $m/n$ itself if, for example, $n=7$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Ops sorry I didn't consider the divisibility also for n, I fix thanks

Comment: In general, $m=n+\lambda \operatorname{lcm}(n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @NgChungTak Yes it is of course the solution for the minimum $m$ but we don't need to take the least one fro the common multiple!

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained a very interesting form of fraction which will follow all the conditions. Unfortunately I am not seasoned in number theory and Hence my solution is lengthy, confusing and has a large no. Of variable, and has a few assumptions. It would be helpful if someone could suggest a better and shorter solution. The form is (210k+2)/(420k+2) .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained a very interesting form of fraction which will follow all the conditions. Unfortunately I am not seasoned in number theory and Hence my solution is lengthy, confusing and has a large no. Of variable, and has a few assumptions. It would be helpful if someone could suggest a better and shorter solution. The form is (210k+2)/(420k+2). After a little maths I found that the common factors are the consecutive prime nos. 3,5,7 also when these divide (m+1),(m+3),(m+5) respectively, the remainder is n as m-n is divisible by 3,5,7 .